# awk field separator , when the separator shows up in double quote

Tags: unix, awk, field, delimiter

I am trying to use awk to read some input at the field position at 3, $3, field 3 is a string

```
awk -F'","' '{print $1}'  input.txt
```

my file *input.txt* looks like this

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5
```

the problem is that these fields are separated by commas, some of them are double quoted while others are not. And field 5 is double quoted and contains every type of symbols. Example:

```
imfield1,imfield2,"imfield3",imfield4,"im"",""fi"",el,""d5"
```

can awk handle a situation like this??
In more gner, how can I get the whole string by typIng $5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Lorance Stinson's Awk CSV parser](http://lorance.freeshell.org/csv/), in which case it's as simple as:

```
function parse_csv(..) {
    ..
}

{
    num_fields = parse_csv($0, csv, ",", "\"", "\"", "\\n", 1);
    print csv[2]
}
```

If you're not hell-bent on Awk, Python also comes with a nice CSV parser:

```
import csv, sys

for row in csv.reader(sys.stdin):
    print row[2]
```

Or from the command line (bit tricky in one line):

```
python -c 'import csv,sys;[sys.stdout.write(row[2]+"\n") for row in csv.reader(sys.stdin)]' < input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The separator is a simple comma, not a comma betweeen quotes. If the fields do not contain commas, then awk may be up for the task:

```
awk -F , '
  {
    if ($3 ~ /^".*"$/) {
        $3 = substr($3, 2, length($3)-2);
        gsub(/""/, "", $3);
     }
     print $3;
  }' input.txt
```

This is already getting pretty complicated. If there can be commas inside fields, use a proper CSV parser, for example in Perl or Python. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/is-there-a-robust-command-line-tool-for-processing-csv-files

Comment: The second example in the question does have commas inside the last field. The actual content (with the quotes processed) is: `im","fi",el,"d5`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the line in `awk` setting null field separator. Instead of `printf("%s",$i)` you can assign `$i` to a var and print out when `inda==0`

```
#echo "\"AAA,BBB\",\"CCC\",\"DDD, EEE, FFF\"" > uno

awk 'BEGIN { FS="" }
{
    for ( i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        if ( $i == "\"" )
            if ( inda == 0 ) 
                inda = 1
            else
                inda = 0
        if ( $i == "," )
            if ( inda == 0 )
                $i="|"
        printf("%s",$i)
    }
    printf("\n")
}' uno
```